# ASP.net MVC: How to access project from mobile via Local Server

Tags: python, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, localserver

Back when I wanted to test my static webpages on mobile, I would set up a Local Http Server using python like.. For example, if my page is at D:/myProject/index.html, I would use command line and go to `>>D:/myProject/`

Then use this line,

```
python -m http.server
```

To set up localhttpserver at port 8000. Then I would access from my mobile browser like

```
http://192.168.XXX.XXX:8000/index.html
```

But I'm very new to ASP MVC Web projects and have no idea **how to access it through localserver** or **how to set up one**. Say, my project is D:/mvcProject/exampleProject.sln. I tried setting up the same way as I did on simple webprojects up to `D:/mvcProject` but when I access the `exampleProject.sln` from browser, it's showing me the codelines instead of the view.

Please do enlighten me, holy light. I, an empty cup, seek for your wisdom.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: @garfbradaz I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .sln file is for keeping together a group of projects that are part of your solution and not for defining the routing or paths. Your route that follows MVC structure is going the include your controller and a view that is tied to that controller. For example, if you have a Controller, `ExampleController`, and a view for that controller, `ExampleDetail.cshtml`,then your path will look something like:

`http://localhost/Example/ExampleDetail`

Please take some time to follow through an MVC tutorial, there are plenty out there.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_mvc/

Comment: Thanks, Dragonborn. That section 'Self-Hosting' at Tutorialspoint was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. Publish your MVC App in Local device.
2. Install IIS (Internet Information Service) from Control panel.
3. Host your app using Local ip.

than Browse your site in mobile from same network

Comment: I see. Thanks! I'll try using IIS instead of python. Do you have any online walkthrough I could follow through? I mean, specifically for MVC.